# jquery window resize causing weird clone issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize

I am using the latest version of jQuery and when I initially load the page the correct number of CSS theater seats are shown within the container. If the user adjusts the width of the window only the arms of the chairs are shown layered on top of one another and the width of the page extends far beyond the width of the window; plus the page freezes.

You can view the CodePen here:
https://codepen.io/ryanindustries8/pen/BJrPMd

```
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        var setSize = function(){
        var blokWidth = $( ".workwithme" ).width();
        var seat = $(".seatBlok").outerWidth();

        var containMe = Math.floor( blokWidth / seat );
        $( "span:first" ).text( containMe );

        var hope = $(".seatBlok");
        for (var i = 1; i < blokWidth; i++){
        hope.clone().insertAfter(hope);
    }}

$( window ).resize(setSize);
    setSize();
})
```

Thank you for any suggestions in advance!

Comment: well you know resize fires multiple times so you keep inserting it.....

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a code pen I made that fixes your immediate issues.](https://codepen.io/wiseman9429/pen/NXeRaK)
There are a number of problems with your code.

Can I suggest you also use your Browser's console (eg Chrome Dev Tools) to learn more about how JS works. I've notated some of your code to show what I mean.
Here is a code pen fork of your work. It's not ideal but a quick fix thats better than what you had I think.

The resize listener you had going, fired off 50+ times in the brief resize that

the [resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) is emitted continuously whilst user resizes.
In my case the `setsize()` function ran 50+ times in a second or two.
To limit how many times this runs, I use [lodash _.debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce). This article also helps explain [debounce / throttling](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).

```
 $( window ).resize(setSize);
 setSize();
```

So, in the 50+ times that `setsize` was called, the `for` loop ran every time.

```
// i increments up to the width of browser (in pixels) 
// my screen is 1920 wide, so this ran many times!
// this resulted in thousands of .seatBlok elements being put into DOM.
for (var i = 1; i < blokWidth; i++){
   hope.clone().insertAfter(hope);
}
```